# How to delete numbers from a vector?

Tags: python, numpy, vector, indexing, multiple-select

I have this vector

```
v = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,20)
```

I want to remove the multiples of 2 and 3. How would I do this?

I tried to do this but I doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
V = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,20)
Mul3 = np.arange(1,21,3)
Mul2 = np.arange(1,21,2)
V1 = V [-mul2]
V2 = V1 [-mul3]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you use NumPy already you can use [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to remove the multiples of `2` and `3`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> v = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,20)  # that's a tuple
>>> arr = np.array(v)  # convert the tuple to a numpy array
>>> arr[(arr % 2 != 0) & (arr % 3 != 0)]
array([ 1,  5,  7, 11, 13, 19])
```

The `(arr % 2 != 0)` creates a boolean mask where multiples of `2` are `False` and everything else `True` and likewise the `(arr % 3 != 0)` works for multiples of `3`. These two masks are combined using `&` (and) and then used as mask for your `arr`

Answer (score 7):

I assume by `vector` you refer to the tuple you set up with the `()`.

You can use a [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) with two conditions, using the `modulo` oprerator you can read up on [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html):

```
res = [i for i in v if not any([i % 2 == 0, i % 3 == 0])]
```

Returns

> [1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 19]

This returns a standard Python list; if you want np arrays or sth, just update your question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the outcome of the modulos 2 and 3 directly for filtering in a *list comprehension*. This keeps items whose `mod 2` and `mod 3` values gives a number other than a *falsy* 0:

```
>>> [i for i in v if i%2 and i%3]
[1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 19]
```

You can make it more verbose if the above is not intuitive enough by making the conditionals explicitly test for non zero outcomes:

```
>>> [i for i in v if not i%2==0 and not i%3==0]
[1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 19]
```