# How to square a component-to-component vector? Python

Tags: python, loops, vector

I want to make the square of a vector, for example this `n = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` and that as a solution `n = (1,4,9,16, 25.36,49,64,81,100)`

Comment: Dude you asked essentially the same question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145640/how-to-delete-numbers-from-a-vector/45145711#45145711) . Just apply the same logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete numbers from a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145640/how-to-delete-numbers-from-a-vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use list comprehension:

```
n = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

new_n = tuple(pow(i, 2) for i in n)
```

Output:

```
(1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100)
```